# Putting Strings in Lexicographic Order

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my assignment, and I am not sure how to proceed. The output only prints my first four teachers, and I don't know why it isn't printing my last three teachers as well. Thanks!

1. Create an ArrayList called teachers. Fill the ArrayList with your teacher’s LAST NAMES ONLY in the order that you see them during the day (Period 1: Jensen, Period 2: Houge, Period 3: …, etc.) You only need to put the teacher’s last name in the ArrayList, so it would print [Jensen, Houge, etc…].) Print the ArrayList using a print method.
2. Write a method that takes your teachers ArrayList, and from it makes a new ArrayList called ordered, whererin your teacher’s names are now in lexicographic order. Print the resulting ArrayList. (DO NOT CHANGE YOUR ORIGINAL ARRAYLIST, MAKE A NEW ONE!)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class LexicographicOrdering
{
   public static void main (String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> teachers = new ArrayList<String>();
        teachers.add("Turnbow");
        teachers.add("Dyvig");
        teachers.add("Williams");
        teachers.add("Houge");
        teachers.add("Allaire");
        teachers.add("Violette");
        teachers.add("Dorgan");
        System.out.println(teachers);
        order(teachers);
   }
    public static void order(ArrayList<String> teachers ){
        ArrayList<String> ordered = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < teachers.size(); i++){
            String str = teachers.get(i);
            for(int j = 1; j < teachers.size(); j++){
                if(str.compareTo(teachers.get(j)) > 0){
                    str = teachers.get(j);
                }
            }
            ordered.add(str);
            teachers.remove(str);
        }
        System.out.print(ordered);
   }
}
```

Comment: `teachers.remove(str);` contradicts "*DO NOT CHANGE YOUR ORIGINAL ARRAYLIST*".

Comment: Even if you were supposed to modify `teachers` (and you're not), it would be a bad idea to do so while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out! I only needed to set the first for loop back to zero. Here is the new code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class LexicographicOrdering
{
   public static void main (String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> teachers = new ArrayList<String>();
        teachers.add("Turnbow");
        teachers.add("Dyvig");
        teachers.add("Williams");
        teachers.add("Houge");
        teachers.add("Allaire");
        teachers.add("Violette");
        teachers.add("Dorgan");
        System.out.println(teachers);
        order(teachers);
   }
    public static void order(ArrayList<String> teachers ){
        ArrayList<String> ordered = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < teachers.size(); i++){
            String str = teachers.get(i);
            for(int j = 1; j < teachers.size(); j++){
                if(str.compareTo(teachers.get(j)) > 0){
                    str = teachers.get(j);  
                }
            }
            i =- 1;
            ordered.add(str);
            teachers.remove(str);
        }
        System.out.print(ordered);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is with your static order method.  As Karl suggests above, you want to break the method into two separate parts.  The first will create an ArrayList named 'ordered' and then fill it with the data contained in the 'teachers' array.

```
    ArrayList<String> ordered = new ArrayList(); //the second <String> is not required
    for(int i = 0; i < teachers.size(); i++){
       String str = teachers.get(i);
       ordered.add(str);
    }
```

The next objective is to sort the array in alphabetical order, which can be achieved using the Collections.sort(ArrayList) method which is contained in the java.util package.

```
    Collections.sort(ordered);
```

And now you need to print the ArrayList.

```
    System.out.println(ordered);
```

As this is a homework assignment, I would recommend reading up on the Collections.sort() method, along with an example of it.  A quick google search pulled up the following website: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java/

Also, I would recommend reading the API for the Collection class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-

Edit:
At a quick glance, I would assume the reason that your string is cutting out the last 3 names is due to the fact that you are removing items from the list as you are looking at each position in the list.  Essentially, you are looking at every other item in the list because of this.